# Skype gtk style not working on debian squeeze 64

Tags: debian, gtk, skype

I have installed skype on my fresh squeeze 64bit system. It works fine except for the fact that the gtk theme isn't really working and the result is quite ugly:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Skype is a proprietary 32-bit application, and cannot use 64-bit Gtk+ theme engines.

Try installing [ia32-libs-gtk](http://packages.debian.org/ia32-libs-gtk), which provides several engines.  If that doesn't work, you'll have to change themes so that you are using an engine which is available in 32-bit.

Comment: Yes I have `ia32-libs-gtk` installed as I thought it would make gtk available to 32bit applications, but skype doesn't seem to care

Comment: It *is* available, otherwise Skype wouldn't run at all.  Your problem is the unavailability of your configured theme engine, thus Skype is falling back to Raleigh.

Answer (score 1):

use `export GTK2_RC_FILES="/etc/gtk-2.0/gtkrc:$HOME/.gtkrc-2.0"`

You can put this in your ~/.bashrc so it is always available.

Also, try this:
run `qtconfig` and choose GTK+ as the theme for qt applications.

Comment: Tried both, no success.

Answer (score 0):

ephemient's idea is intriguing. Try installing other GTK engines and switching to them to see whether Skype is able to use the new ones without falling back to Raleigh. I know it sounds nightmarish, but you can also run Skype under strace and see what files it fails to open (if any). Also, what engine are you using? Gnome/GTK 2 or 3?

As another data point, I'm running it under Ubuntu 11.10 64-bit with Unity and Radiosity and it picks up the engine correctly.

A final note: I would comment on epemient's answer, but I suffer from low karma here. :-(