# Skype - not using GTK+

Tags: arch-linux, gtk, skype

I am on a x64 Archlinux running openbox DE and have been strugling for some time now to configure Skype to use my GTK+ theme which i set to Oxygen.

I have tried following [this wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Skype#Skype_does_not_use_my_GTK.2B_theme.2C_even_though_other_Qt_apps_do) as well as [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34319/skype-gtk-style-not-working-on-debian-squeeze-64) and none has worked out for me. I have already installed lib32-gtk-engines package from Archlinux [AUR packages site](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/lib32-gtk-engines/). Still Skype wont change its appearance.

The GTK+ theme is set as you can see:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Skype uses Qt, not Gtk+. You can check the libraries with the `ldd` command:

```
> ldd /usr/lib32/skype/skype | grep Qt
    libQtDBus.so.4 => /usr/lib32/libQtDBus.so.4 (0xf57aa000)
    libQtWebKit.so.4 => /usr/lib32/libQtWebKit.so.4 (0xf40fa000)
    libQtXml.so.4 => /usr/lib32/libQtXml.so.4 (0xf40b6000)
    libQtGui.so.4 => /usr/lib32/libQtGui.so.4 (0xf35e1000)
    libQtNetwork.so.4 => /usr/lib32/libQtNetwork.so.4 (0xf349c000)
    libQtCore.so.4 => /usr/lib32/libQtCore.so.4 (0xf31ac000)
```

My guess would be that it may have used Gtk+ in the past, hence the wiki page, but that it changed to Qt sometime in the past year.

Comment: Since it ships it's own Qt libraries, I don't think it would be even possible to make it use QGtkStyle to make it 'blend' better in a GTK desktop :/

Answer (score 0):

To allow Skype to use GTK+ themes you need to do this:

Fixing Skype Theme = 1. Add the following line to the ~/.gtkrc-2.0 file (if there is no such a file, create it by hand):
        gtk-theme-name="the name of your GTK+ theme"
2. Add the following line to the ~/.profile:
        export GTK2_RC_FILES="$HOME/.gtkrc-2.0"
3. Finally, make a logout and a login or just restart the computer.

I do this and my Skype now has the same theming as the rest of my computer. Please let me know if you this helped you.